# JQL is not working as per expected

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api

This is an interesting thing. I created a JIRA issue using a java rest client provided by JIRA(JiraRestClient). When I try to search the issue in the JIRA ui by using JQL in advanced search

**reporter = user123**(where user123 is the user i used to create the issue)

I can't find that issue in the results. But when I manually update that issue.. say comment on it and then run the above query again I see that issue in the results.

Can anyone explain why is this happening ?

Comment: How, exactly, are you creating the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQL relies on lucene index and looks like issues created by the JiraRestClient are not indexed till you update them (issue is indexed on update). For me it sounds like a bug. 
To be sure please launch full reindex https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Search+Indexing and then try to reproduce your case.